# I have a problem avetr mageto upgrate from 2.3 to 2.4.5

Tags: magento2

I can't run the php bin/magento setup:di:compile
If i do this i got this error.

```
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 117.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected identifier "ApplyStockConditionToSelect", expecting "{"#0 /home/magento1/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 /home/magento1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#3 /home/magento1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#4 /home/magento1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#5 /home/magento1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#6 /home/magento1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#7 /home/magento1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#8 /home/magento1/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#9 /home/magento1/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1021): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#10 /home/magento1/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(275): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#11 /home/magento1/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#12 /home/magento1/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#13 /home/magento1/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

i disabled the search engine with this command bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine none

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Without sharing a single line of code, it's close to impossible to tell you what is going wrong

Comment: i have only tried to make one update.
from version 2.3.5 to 2.4.5 and when i call the command bin/magento setup:di:compile i get this error message.
i have also deleted the entire vendor folder and rebuilt it with composer. but that didn't work for me anyway.

Comment: @MichaelMüller Have you found any solution for this? I am facing same issue after upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue Edit vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/SelectBuilderForAttribute.php

on line 11 see if ApplyStockConditionToSelect is moved to second line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Editinng code in the vendor folder is never a good idea, as such changes are overwritten when updating packages